# easy way to share 2fa codes both app and text based

Tags: multi-factor

With COVID and everything happening, I have been thinking of death and estate  planning a lot lately.

I have added my family to my password manager, but not sure what is the easy way to share 2FA authentication across a range of websites both text and app-based. The only thing I can think of is moving everything to app-based and print 2FA backup codes and keep it in the password manager. Is there any other better way that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You should move off of SMS-based 2FA anyway, so do that immediately.

Printing off 2FA codes is meant to be used in this sort of situation. You can keep them in a digital safe (like a password manager) or physically printed and stored in a physically safe place (safe, safe deposit box, lawyer, etc.).

So, your approach is pretty standard for basic digital estate planning. It's low-resource, everything is easy for your loved ones to find, and you have basic on-going security in place.

Answer (score -1):

Use a [Yubikey](https://www.yubico.com/). Very simple to use for 2fa access of sites.

For sites that don't support 2fa, just lock the username/password details in a password manager which is protected by 2fa.